# MCP2200 - which GPIOs for DTR, DCD, DSR and RI?

Tags: serial, gpio, usb-device

Due to the recent controversy surrounding FTDI, I'm looking for a replacement for future designs. I'm looking very hard at the MCP2200. The only thing I can't figure out is that they have several GPIO pins, but none of them are explicitly marked as being intended for DTR, DSR, DCD or RI. RI is certainly optional, but depending on what I'm using it for, I'd rather not do without the other 3. Are these signals supported by the default drivers? If so, then which pins do they use?

Comment: Seems like Microchip didn't bother to include those functions in the MCP2200. I've been using a SiLabs CP2102 for almost 10 years now without any trouble. It's got all of the pins and doesn't need an external osc or crystal either.

Comment: @brhans Yeah, I found that chip, but I'm not a fan of the QFN package. If they had an SOIC or SSOP, we wouldn't be having this conversation.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a bit late for your review but have a look at the new Cypress USB to serial bridges. They are apparently able to mimic the footprint of the FT232R and feature the required modem control lines:

http://www.cypress.com/?id=4&rID=83118

and

http://www.cypress.com/?mpn=CY7C65213-28PVXI

We have done some early testing with the controllers and appear to be fine. Based on the Cortex M0 processor but the firmware is not available.

Comment: Yeah, I went with the Cypress one that has the FTDI footprint and uses a generic driver. Works quite nicely.